# Embedd hyperlink in one column of details DataTables rows

Tags: javascript, html, python-2.7, datatables

This is a follow on question from [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487794/datatables-javascript-library-and-nested-json)

From the accepted response I was able to get the table working as shown in the JS Fiddle below

```
`var data = {"data":[{"student_name":"jack","subjects":{"math":{"cat1_grade":"30","cat2_grade":"39","cat3_grade":"38"},"english":{"cat1_grade":"30","cat2_grade":"39","cat3_grade":"38"},"swahili":{"cat1_grade":"30","cat2_grade":"39","cat3_grade":"38"}},"subject1_average":"35","subject2_average":"26","subject3_average":"59"}]};

/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    var header = false;
    var detail_table = $("<table></table>",{
        "cellpadding":"5",
        "cellspacing": "0",
        "border": "0",
        "style":"padding-left:50px;"
    });
    var tbody = $("<tbody></tbody>");
    detail_table.append(tbody);
    $.each(d.subjects, function(k, v){
        var tbody_row = $("<tr></tr>").append($("<td></td>",{"text": k}));
        if(!header){
            var thead = $("<thead></thead>");
            var thead_row = $("<tr></tr>")
            thead_row.append($("<th></th>",{"text":" "}));
            $.each(v, function(a, b){
                thead_row.append($("<th></th>",{"text":a}));
                tbody_row.append($("<td></td>",{"text":b}));
            });
            thead.append(thead_row);
            detail_table.append(thead);          
            header = true;
        }else{
            $.each(v, function(a, b){
                tbody_row.append($("<td></td>",{"text":b}));
            });
        }
        tbody.append(tbody_row);     
    });
    return detail_table;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": {
            "url": '/echo/js/?js=' + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data)),
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "student_name" },
            { "data": "subject1_average" },
            { "data": "subject2_average" },
            { "data": "subject3_average" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );

    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
```

[JS Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/mqrckaft/)

However I would really like to get one of the details columns to be a hyperlink. So to be specific how would I make the student's math column be a hyperlink so that when the user clicks on math they are navigated to the math.html link e.g "http://math.com".

Just to be clear I believe

```
$.each(v, function(a, b){
                tbody_row.append($("<td></td>",{"text":b}));
            });
```

Is the portion that is creating the row, what I'd like is to have elemnt X of that row to be a hyperlink while all the other elements can be text.
I don't really understand javascript so I think that `{"text":b}` is adding the elements as text to the row. But I don't know how to specify element X of the object v to be a URL, while keeping the rest of the elements of v, as text

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760613/jquery-datatable-is-it-possible-to-bind-href-property-of-link-with-razor-syntax/32778950#32778950)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
var tbody_row = $("<tr></tr>").append($("<td></td>",{"text": k}));
```

to

```
var tbody_row = $("<tr></tr>").append($("<td></td>",{"html": '<a href="' + k + '.html">' + k + '</a>'}));
```

to construct links to `math.html` when subject is `math`.

See [updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqrckaft/2/) for code and demonstration.